# 'Calling' UseEffect from another 'UseEffect'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm learning react native and I'm programing a simple app to register the time of sleep of each day.

When the button that add the new register is pressed I do this

```
onPress={() => setUpdateAction(true)}
```

That changes the value of the updateAction:

const [updateAction, setUpdateAction] = useState(false);

When the value of updateAction is changed this will be executed:

```
useEffect(() => {

    ... code that add's the register to an array

    setviewInfoAction(true);
    setUpdateAction(false);
}, [updateAction]);
```

And inside I call `setviewInfoAction(true);` becouse I want to change the value that is showed with the value that was inserted.

```
const [viewInfoAction, setviewInfoAction] = useState(false);


useEffect(() => {
        console.log("CALLED");
        var seted = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < registSleep.length; i++) {
            if (
                registSleep[i].day === selectedDay &&
                registSleep[i].month === selectedMonth &&
                registSleep[i].year === selectedYear
            ) {
                setSelectedDayHours(registSleep[i].hours);
                seted = true;
            }
        }
        if (!seted) {
            setSelectedDayHours(0);
        }
        setviewInfoAction(false);
    }, [viewInfoAction]);
```

Doing this I was expecting for the second UseEffect to executed but it's not...

Comment: Just add the value, changed by first useEffect, into the second useEffect dependencies. In your case, I guess, it should be `updateAction`

Answer (score 0):

The way you have your useEffect set up it will only ever re-run if `selectedDay` changes.  If you want to make it run when `setInfoViewAction` is executed add `viewInfoAction` into the dependencies.

Even better because all of this is related logic to the same sideEffect.  I would simplify your code by removing the second `useEffect` and adding the code inside it into the first `useEffect`.  This is mainly just because you can keep all related side effect logic together.

Comment: I had viewInfoAction on the dependecies of the UseEffect, I must had changed it just to try other ways but it does not work either. But I just solved the problem. I think it had troubles becouse it was executing the 2 UseEffects at same time since the setUpdateAction(false); will trigger the UseEffect again and i dont want tha behavior so  my solution is just toggle to the opposite value of  viewInfoAction and updateAction